# Paw - A way to make the chosen request/response tab sticky when moving between requests

Tags: paw-app

In Paw each tab choice I make, e.g "URL params" request tab, is saved per request.

So if I switched to another request, the tab would jump to "Description" or whatever was chosen last.

Is there a way to make the UI to be consistent between requests? It would make it much easier when I'm comparing multiple requests, for example.

Comment: Unfortunately, not. As you said, the preference is saved per request. I can see why it would be better to be a global preference and not per request, but some users seem to like it better per request, depending on their workflow. Maybe it's something that we should add to the app's Preferences window. Do you confirm that it does persist correctly per request (when coming back to an existing request, it opens the last tab)?

Comment: @MichaMazaheri Yes, it does. Adding it to preferences would be great.